# Anyone using Magazinenews theme on Wordpress to say where to put the_content code for Elementor?

Tags: wordpress, themes, elementor

I just created new homepage with elementor plugin on Wordpress. But when I tried to edit, I get error message. I understood that I must to add  to the theme. But I don't know where in my theme Magazinews. I tried in "page.php" and "index.php", but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

The the_content() missing doesn't really mean your theme is missing the content. Also, since you were able to edit that page before ( when you created it ) your theme obviously has the_content() there.

In this case, try disabling other plugins and see if that helps. If it does enable them one by one and you should be able to find the culprit.

If you left any information behind make sure to add it.